# csv file filtering

Tags: sed, awk

I have a .csv file with a header row like so;

```
headerA,headerB,headerC
bill,jones,p
mike,smith,f
sally,silly,p
```

I'd like to filter out any records with the f value in the headerC column.

Can I do that with sed or awk?

Comment: Note that [CSV](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) may contain embedded line breaks, so any pure line-based solution might do wrong things with certain inputs. Furthermore, quoted values may pose problems with plenty of naïve approaches to the problem.

Comment: @Joey, right. Usual recommendation is to use a language with a dedicated CSV library, such as [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm)

Answer (score 8):

If header does not contains only `f` at the third columns name:

```
sed '/,f$/d' FILE
```

will do (deletes every line from the input if it ends with `,f`).

If it has, I'd go with:

```
sed -n -e '1p;/,[^f]$/p' FILE
```

(Does not print anything by default (`-n`) but the 1st line must `1p`, and if the lines are ends with other char than `f`... **Note:** this will not work, if the 3rd columnc contains more than one char.)

And an `awk` one:

```
awk -F, 'NF == 1 ; NF > 1 && $3 != "f"' FILE
```

(This always prints the first line (`NF == 1` is true, then default action, which is `print $0`, then the next condtitions are checking if we had got over the 1st line, and the 3rd field is not `f` then default action...)

HTH

Comment: Your second sed solution will break if the 3rd column contains >1 char. Better to stick with the 1st sed or awk as it implements the requirements more precisely (delete line if "f")

Comment: According to the "specification": "I'd like to filter out any records with the f value in the headerC column."
So it's correct IMO.

Comment: If the 3rd column contains "ab", that does not match `/,[^f]$/` so it will be filtered.

Comment: You were right @glennjackman if the 3rd column is longer than 1 char, it will not be printed, updating the desc.

Answer (score 3):

well, if you know that `headerC` is always in the third column, the following sed command would work:

`sed -r '/[^,]+(,[^,]+){1},f/ d' < file.csv > filefiltered.csv`

And the following awk command does the same:

`awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {if($3 != "f") print}' file.csv`

If you don't know `headerC` is always in a particular column it gets a little more tricky. Does this work?

Comment: The awk command can be simplified: `awk -F, '$3 != "f"' file.csv`

Comment: @glenn it can indeed. but I never bothered to look up if -F was a gnu extension or not, so i just went with the safest. I'll take that to mean it isn't :)

Answer (score 2):

grep works, look at example.

```
grep ",.*,.*f" << EOF
headerA,headerB,headerC
bill,josef,p
mike,smith,f
sally,silly,p
EOF
```

outputs:

```
mike,smith,f
```

Comment: Nice, clean and quick (ps. don't need the final .*)

Answer (score 1):

A bit unclear, is this what you are asking for?

```
$ awk -F, '{ if($3 == "f")print}' input
mike,smith,f
```

With a header and formatted using `column`

```
$ awk -F, '{ if (NR == 1)print}{if($3 == "f")print}' input | column -t -s,
headerA  headerB  headerC
mike     smith    f
```

Answer (score -2):

no need for sed or awk, this can be done with more simpler commands like cut and grep piped together like this

```
cut -d"," -f 3| grep -i f
```

I am assuming the delimiter is coma and Column c is thrid one. if it si not change the values above appropriately. And i have used grep with i option so that it ignore case. If you want to match only lowercse f or upppercase f then remove the i option and change it accordingly.

Comment: That will only output values from the 3rd field, not the whole line.